# Generate a clock for only test in COCOTB not connected to the DUT

Tags: python, cocotb

I am new to cocotb and I want to test my DUT.

I have one clock that input to the dut which i generate correctly, however,
I want a clock to use it only in the test not connected to the DUT, I want this clock to be long and with each rising edge a do a test but O am suffering since yesterday to do such a clock

I have the following code

```
import cocotb
from cocotb.runner import get_runner
from cocotb.triggers import Timer, FallingEdge, RisingEdge
from cocotb.clock import Clock

    async def generate_clock(sim_clk, period):
    """Generate clock test."""
    while True:
        sim_clk <= 0
        await Timer(period // 2, units="ms")
        sim_clk <= 1
        await Timer(period // 2, units="ms")

@cocotb.test()
async def top(dut):
sim_clk = Clock('sim_clk', period=22)
cocotb.start_soon(generate_clock(sim_clk, 22))
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
## this line is alwys error I tried everything but it gives error
await RisingEdge(dut.sim_clk)
```

How can make such clock I can use its rising edge but not eonnected to the dut

Comment: @OysterShucker, I already said, I am new to python, and if you used cocotb, you will know what I mean, yes, I thought, it will be clear without adding the error however, you are very disrespectful and harsh. I dont need your help and I will remove my acount after one day to make sure you read my comment. If being disrespectful makes you think, you are better, you are totally mistaken.

Comment: You can claim whatever you want. You aren't new to asking questions, you've been asking them your entire life. This site doesn't support implied problems so, leaving your code broken, and failing to post the exact error has left your question unanswerable, regardless of what packages someone is familiar with. All you have to do is recognize that not one person gave you an answer, and it becomes obvious your question is poor. Arguing with me and being hyper-emotional isn't solving your problem.

Comment: Taking what I said and improving your question was the real action you should have taken. It seems like you are more worried about suffering from extreme confidence issues than getting your script to work.

Comment: @OysterShucker, I am sorry my question is poor, and I knew this now, however it is not practical to disrespect someone for teaching him something. I solved the bug by myself and the test is working. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was cocotb prefer working with dut.clk and in case we want to make a clk only for the tesbench this will raise an issue for cocotb, I overcome this issue by adding a clock to the dut which only for the test and it passed.
I searched a lot and using a delay for clock in cocotb is not a practical use.

```
clock_tb = Clock(dut.clk_tb, 22, units="ms")

cocotb.start_soon(clock_tb.start(start_high=False)) # it is important to start with falling edge

await RisingEdge(dut.clk_tb)
```

I belive this is the best use of the clock in cocotb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnteK.png)